# What is the correct way to translate variable_get string values entered in admin input fields?

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n, configuration

I'm developing a simple module with and admin page, where admin can fill some textfields with custom strings that will generates a piece of html to be used later.

So for example I have fields like this in admin page:

```
function MYMODULE_admin_page_arguments() {
  $form = array();

  $form['MYMODULE_link'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Conditions link path'),
    '#default_value' => variable_get('MYMODULE_link', 'conditions'),
  );
  $form['MYMODULE_link_text'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Conditions link text'),
    '#default_value' => variable_get('MYMODULE_link_text', 'conditions'),
  );
  $form['MYMODULE_link_target'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Conditions link target'),
    '#default_value' => variable_get('MYMODULE_link_target', '_blank'),
  );
  $form['MYMODULE_prefix'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Conditions link prefix text'),
    '#default_value' => variable_get('MYMODULE_prefix', 'I agree to the '),
  );
  $form['MYMODULE_suffix'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Conditions link suffix text'),
    '#default_value' => variable_get('MYMODULE_suffix', '.'),
  );

  return system_settings_form($form);
}
```

Then the above values are managed after by my module to compose an output like:

```
// Create label
$prefix = variable_get('MYMODULE_prefix', 'I agree to the ');
$suffix = variable_get('MYMODULE_suffix', '.');
$path = variable_get('MYMODULE_link', 'conditions');
$text = variable_get('MYMODULE_link_text', 'conditions');
$target = variable_get('MYMODULE_link_target', '_blank');

$label = $prefix . l($text, $path, array('attributes' => array('target' => $target))) . $suffix;
```

Now I need that all these values are available for string translation, so the first think I thought was to pass all of them through t(), for example:

```
$label = t($prefix) . l(t($text), $path, array('attributes' => array('target' => $target))) . t($suffix);
```

but I read here https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/t/7 that I should never pass variables directly to t(), so for e.g t($prefix) is a bad stuff.

So, what is the correct Drupal way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the Variable translation module, part of [Internationalization](https://www.drupal.org/project/i18n).

1. Enable the Variable translation module included with the *Internationalization* package
2. Go to *Administration > Configuration > Regional and language > Multilingual settings*
3. Click on the *Variables* tab
4. Select the variables that will be multilingual
5. Click *Save configuration* button

Then, you'll be able to select language for which you are configuring your variable:

[image: Screenshot from community documentation]

Advice taken from [this community documentation](https://www.drupal.org/node/1113374).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but In this case I'll have to introduce a non-core module dependency: I hope there is a core-based solution to this simple "every-day" (I think) necessity

Comment: @MXT Nope. Built in support is limited. Internationalization module was created exactly to fill up the gaps. You can either use i18n as it is, or try to duplicate it, but I see no point in using second option. Someone wrote it already. See [NIH philosophy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Not_invented_here) - are you sure that's not what you are doing now?

Comment: Thank you Molot for your explanation, the issue is more clearer now. I think that in my specific case, where these fields are not public but populated only in protected admin pages by administrators (= trusted people), security risks are minimal so I could however try the use of t($variable). On the other hand the t() API page just suggests "You **should** never use t() to translate variables", not that it is absolutely forbidden... I don't know, I'd like to get more opinions on this